# How to define constraint having two columns with boolean column to be true only once

Tags: postgresql, database-design, unique-constraint, exclusion-constraint

Let the table to be considered is this:

```
create table users(
email varchar(50) not null,
is_verified boolean default false,
);
```

Now, how can I define the `exclusion` constraint here so that if the `is_verified` column is true once for an email, that email ***cannot*** be inserted anymore?

Comment: So you would allow the same email twice if both are not verfied? OK, then you verify one and ... booom?

Comment: Ooops, how fool of me.. 
So I guess there's no option without checking before inserting..

Comment: You can still just INSERT. With an appropriate constraint in place, Postgres will tell you when it can't be done, and you handle the exception accordingly. That's actually the safe way under concurrent write load.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Partial `UNIQUE` index

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON users (email) WHERE is_verified;
```

This way you allow any email as long as it's not verified. (That's actually what the title asks - as opposed to the question body.)

**Do this in any case.** It enforces a subset of the rules you are trying to implement in a bullet-proof fashion - the most crucial part, I assume. Plus, the index greatly helps performance when looking up verified emails, which you are going to do a lot.

#### The rest of your rule set

... could be covered with a trigger. Based on this slightly modified table definition:

````
``` 
CREATE TABLE users (
  user_id int GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
, email text                               -- allow null?
, is_verified bool DEFAULT false NOT NULL  -- not null!
);
````

Trigger function & trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trg_users_semi_uniq_emails()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   CASE NEW.is_verified
   WHEN false THEN
      IF EXISTS (
         SELECT FROM users u
         WHERE  u.email = NEW.email
         AND    u.is_verified
         ) THEN
         -- ?raise exception?
         -- RAISE EXCEPTION 'Verified email already exists: %', NEW.email;

         -- ?or cancel operation on this row silently?
         -- RETURN NULL;

         -- ?orset this email null?
         -- NEW.email := NULL;
      END IF;

   WHEN true THEN
      IF EXISTS (
         SELECT FROM users u
         WHERE  u.email = NEW.email
         AND    NOT u.is_verified  -- "is_verified" covered by partial unique idx
         ) THEN         
         -- ?set all other emails null?
         -- UPDATE users u SET email = NULL WHERE u.email = NEW.email;
         
         -- ?or one of the above?
      END IF;
   END CASE;

   RETURN NEW;
END
$func$;

CREATE TRIGGER users_bef_insup
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON users
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.email IS NOT NULL)
EXECUTE FUNCTION trg_users_semi_uniq_emails();
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/vEYVNKLg)

Enforces the rest. Might still be good enough but - because of inherent race conditions - not as bullet-proof as the unique index. Very competitive concurrent transactions altering the same emails at the same time can find a loophole.

Comment: No, look.. I want duplicate email.. if all are not verified.. but once its verified, no more entry - verified or unverified. But now I understand the entire objective is not possible with any constraint.

Comment: Your answer is the is the closest that I can get. Thanks.

Comment: @Muzib you can check the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/dwhxEwkD)

Comment: @SahapAsci: Thanks, I built on your fiddle.

Comment: @Muzib I added a bit to get you closer, yet.

Answer (score 0):

Seems pretty straightforward, unless I'm missing something:

```
create table users(
 email varchar(50) not null,
 is_verified boolean default false,

 exclude (email with =) where (is_verified)
);
```

Comment: But this doesn't prevent inserting the same email with is_verified = false, does it?

Comment: This exclusion constraint is an expensive way of implementing a partial unique index (with a gist index instead of btree). It would require the additional module `btree_gist`. Don't do it.

Comment: @Muzib, if you want to prevent that, why not make email unique?

Comment: @Lennart-SlavaUkraini that's not the objective. Anybody can use anyone's email to create an account. But the actual account holder can verify the email.

Comment: Perhaps I misread your question to mustaccio. Anyhow, you should make is_verified NOT NULL.